# autorelease makes my app crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, memory-management

My app crashes sometimes at this point:

```
NSMutableData* position = [NSMutableData dataWithLength: 3 * sizeof(CGPoint)];
```

when `NSMutableData` calls the autorelease.

Here's the crash log:

> ```
> Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
> Exception Codes: 0x00000001, 0xe7ffdefe
> Crashed Thread:  0
>
> Thread 0 name:
> Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
> Thread 0 Crashed:
> 0   CoreFoundation            0x343dea60 _CFAutoreleasePoolAddObject + 136
> 1   CoreFoundation                0x343de9cc -[NSObject(NSObject) autorelease] + 8
> 2   Foundation                0x30c49166 +[NSMutableData(NSMutableData) dataWithLength:] + 34
> ```

Do you have any idea why?

**UPDATE:**
The variable "position" is returned and used this way:

```
    NSMutableData *positionData = [[SFinder sharedFinder] move:self.crId] ;
CGPoint *path = [positionData mutableBytes];
CGPoint location0 = path[0];

CGPoint location1 = path[1];

CGPoint location = path[2];
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I removed the code with NSMutableData, but the app keeps crashing randomly. On the debug console there is a message:

> ```
> *** attempt to pop an unknown autorelease pool (0x5830000)
> ```

stack:

> ```
> Thread 0 Crashed:
>    Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
> 0   CoreFoundation               0x01348b69 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 201
> 1   UIKit                        0x008a947c _wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler + 68
> 2   CoreFoundation               0x013edfbb __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 27
> 3   CoreFoundation               0x013830e7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 295
> 4   CoreFoundation               0x0134bbd7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575
> 5   CoreFoundation               0x0134b240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
> 6   CoreFoundation               0x0134b161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
> 7   GraphicsServices             0x029b3268 GSEventRunModal + 217
> 8   GraphicsServices             0x029b332d GSEventRun + 115
> 9   UIKit         0x008a942e UIApplicationMain + 1160
> 10  MyApp                        0x000029f4 main + 100 (main.m:13)
> 11  MyApp                        0x00002985 start + 53
> ```

Comment: Do you mean you are calling autorelease yourself?

Comment: @HyLian: It doesn't look like it.  Check out the stack trace.

Comment: Perhaps you release it yourself somewhere ? Or assign it to another variable that you release ?

Comment: Where is that code? Do you know whether an autorelease pool exists at that point?

Comment: What if you try to alloc / init it yourself without using the auto method ?

Comment: @depontgabor: Have you done anything strange with the autorelease pool?  It looks like it has got corrupted somehow.

Comment: @depontgabor: Where did you copy the stack trace from that had it so badly formatted?

Comment: @depontgabor: Run your app under Instruments's Zombies template. This sounds kind of like you're overreleasing an autorelease pool, but some parts of this still don't make sense. Instruments will give you much more information; please edit your question to include it.

Comment: @Oliver: Avoiding autorelease is a poor solution, both because it is impossible (any serious work in Cocoa needs to use an autoreleasing method sooner or later) and because it does not address the problem (why is autorelease flaking out?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. There is an issue with `NSMutableData`. It occures when you init it with `initWithLength`, or `dataWithLength` and try to insert data trough `mutableBytes`. When you insert the last byte it makes some allocation somewhere else (even if that part of the memory is owned by an other object) causing `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and other memory related errors. So initiating it with length+1 bytes solved the problem.

Comment: Allocating memory does not cause `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`; accessing memory you haven't allocated does (that is what it means by “bad access”). It sounds like you were creating the data with a length that was less than you were copying into it; copying directly into the data's buffer does not cause it to reallocate, because the object has no way of knowing that you're writing into its buffer, where in it you're writing, or how much you're writing. It might help if you would edit your question to include the code that copied into the data, not just the code that copies out from it.

Answer (score 0):

> when NSMutableData calls the
>   autorelease.

??

it calls autorelease by itself?
meaning?
do you use:

```
[position release];
```

or

```
[position autorelease];
```

if so... well, don't do it... you don't really need it, if you initiated it with just the code you wrote in your question...

Answer (score 0):

Did you retain the variable "position" in any other code? Typically if you released it and then later on autoreleasepool is drained, thus releasing it again, when it doesn't exist anymore. Please [see this post for possible details](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/87251-how-do-debug-an-autorelease-crash.html).

Also you shouldn't have your variable call autorelease on itself (if you are).

Answer (score 0):

Either:

1) There's something up with the enclosing autorelease pool (where is it? Is it one you defined yourself, or is it the default one?)

or

2) Something is releasing your `NSMutableData* position` when it shouldn't be. It is doing it before the current NSAutoreleasePool leaves its scope, sending the retain count to 0 and causing dealloc to be called -- and then when the autorelease pool itself calls `release`, you're crashing out because the object has already been dealloc'd.

Comment: I use the default autorelease pool. The variable "position" is returned and used in an other method, but I don't retain or release it.

Comment: According to the stack trace, in the first exception, the object has not even been returned yet—`dataWithLength:` has not returned yet. The exception occurred when it tried to autorelease the object *initially*.

Answer (score 0):

The object the "position" variable refers to is automatically placed into the default autorelease pool by virtue of the fact that it originates from an NSMutableData convenience method.  It may be that the default autorelease pool is no longer valid.  I'm just guessing here.

In any case, objects in the default autorelease pool are guaranteed to be retained only for as long as the life of the current event context.  This might have something to do with what your are seeing.

I would suggest you try making the "position" variable an instance property with attribute "retain".  This will give you more control on the lifetime of the "position" object.  Don't forget to release the "position" object in your class's dealloc method.

In all of my iOS apps, I rely heavily on the declared properties feature provided by the objective C framework.  If I desire an object to "stick around" for awhile, I refer to it with a declared property with attribute "retain".  Then I have a much clearer idea as to exactly how long it will remain valid.  I also have more control on it's lifetime.

Hope this helps.

- Let It Be Known

Comment: Assigning an autoreleased object to a retaining property won't help if you get a crash during the initial autorelease. I agree that there doesn't seem to be a pool in effect, but that makes no sense; objects are valid “as long as the life of the current event context” because UIApplication creates a pool around the response to every event, so there should always be an autorelease pool when your code runs on the main thread.